# tf.image.sobel_edges: InvalidArgumentError: The first dimension of paddings must be the rank of inputs[4,2], [400,400,3] [Op:MirrorPad]

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, face-recognition

Please I need help

I am using tensorflow for a computer vision task. My function works fine without `tf.image.sobel_edges()`, but when I use it I get this error. I need to achieve two things from this function

1. have contours around my images
2. have shape of 4 dimensions

```py
def preprocess(file_path):
    
    # Read in image from file path
    byte_img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    # Load in the image 
    img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(byte_img)
    
    #add contours using tensorflow
    img = tf.image.sobel_edges(img)
    
    
    # Preprocessing steps - resizing the image to be 100x100x4
    img = tf.image.resize(img, (100,100,4))
    
    # Scale image to be between 0 and 1 
    img = img / 255.0
    
    # Return image
    return img

#use function 
img = preprocess('data\\picture(75).jpg')
```

Comment: What happens when you run `img = tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0)` before calling `img = tf.image.sobel_edges(img)`?

Comment: it gives a new error:  InvalidArgumentError: Value for attr 'T' of uint8 is not in the list of allowed values: half, bfloat16, float, double
 ; NodeDef: {{node DepthwiseConv2dNative}}; Op<name=DepthwiseConv2dNative; signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE]; attr=strides:list(int); attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID", "EXPLICIT"]; attr=explicit_paddings:list(int),default=[]; attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", "NCHW"]; attr=dilations:list(int),default=[1, 1, 1, 1]> [Op:DepthwiseConv2dNative]

Comment: Cast your image to float? `img = tf.cast(img, tf.float32)` before `tf.image.sobel_edges(img)`..Maybe read the docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/sobel_edges

Comment: it says ValueError: 'images' must have either 3 or 4 dimensions. okay let me read the doc. Thank you

Comment: You have to use both `tf.expand_dims` and `tf.cast`.

Comment: thank you so much. I converted the image to an array before casting and expand_dims
image=np.array(image)
image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
image=tf.compat.v1.expand_dims(image, 0)
sobel= tf.image.sobel_edges(image)

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow model usually expects a batch of images. Thank means, after your preprocess step, you need to add one more dimension for the batch and add the image as first in the set. You can use numpy and do this by:

```
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
```